# my bubble sort wont swap when list have more than 3 objects. JAVA

Tags: java, linked-list, bubble-sort

My bubble sort does not work if i have more than 3 objects in the stack. how come?
if i push **a, b, c.** The bubble sort will sort them: **c,b,a** which is correct. 
But if i have **a,b,c,d.** The bubble sort will sort them to:**a,d,c,b.** 
And if i have **a,b,c,d,e.** The bubble sort will sort them to: **a,b,e,d,c,b.**

My node class:

```
public class Stack implements StackAPI{

public Stack(){
}

private Node first = null;
private int size = 0;

private class Node implements Comparable<Node>{
    String item;
    Node next;

    public String getItem(){
        return this.item;
    }
    public int compareTo(Node other){

        if(getItem().compareTo(other.getItem()) > 0){
            return 1;
        }

        else if(getItem().compareTo(other.getItem()) < 0){
            return -1;
        }
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Bubble sort function:

```
public void bubbleSort(){
    int N = size;
    boolean swapped = true;


    while(swapped == true){
        Node currentNode = first;
        swapped = false;


        for(int i=0; i < N-1; i++){
            if(less(currentNode.next, currentNode)){

                exch(currentNode);
                swapped = true;
            }

            currentNode = first.next;
        }
    }
}
```

The less and exch functions:

```
private static boolean less(Comparable v, Comparable w){
    return v.compareTo(w) < 0;
}

private static void exch(Node a) {
    String swap = a.item;
    a.item = a.next.item;
    a.next.item = swap;
}
```

Comment: You should do some debugging.

Comment: To start, replace you whole `compareTo` method with this line: `return getItem().compareTo(other.getItem());`. That makes it a lot shorter and easier to understand, and you can focus your debugging elsewhere.

Comment: @erwin-bolwidt much worse is to change node values in exch() method, rather then changing links between nodes. yes, it works, but it is ugly from design point of view

Comment: oki, so its not ideal to just change the values? How can i implement code to change the links?

Comment: @ursa if i want to change the links. then i need to have a Node previous aswell?

Comment: you may, but it is not required. you can keep previous element (null on iteration start) and update it in the same manner as current one.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem is here:

```
    for(int i=0; i < N-1; i++){
        if(less(currentNode.next, currentNode)){

            exch(currentNode);
            swapped = true;
        }

        //currentNode = first.next; // <== here?
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
    }
```

Correct way:

```
    for (Node curr = first, next = curr.next; next != null; next = curr.next) {
        if (next >= curr) {
            curr = next;
            continue;
        }
        // update head, if required
        if (first == curr) {
            first = next;
        }
        // swap elements
        curr.next = next.next;
        next.next = curr;
        swapped = true;
    }
```